# Updating entire google sheet workbook using pygsheets

Tags: python, pygsheets

This is my current code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(any_dictionary)
sh = gc.open('test_workbook')

try: # if sheet doesn't exist, create
    wks = sh.worksheet_by_title('Test')
except:
    wks = sh.add_worksheet('Test')

wks.set_dataframe(df,(1,1), fit=True, nan='')
```

The problem I'm having is upload speed. If I use this method on 100+ individual sheets, I have to wait more than an hour, due to the speed of uploading each one. It would be much easier if I could just upload & overwrite entire workbooks, each containing the sheets. Can I do this in pygsheets or perhaps another library?

Comment: this is not possible in pyghseets out of the box. but you can use the custom_request to send all your data at once.